# Criar funções em Python

Tags: python, funções

Desejo criar uma função que receba um vetor de 10 registros, na qual em cada possua nome, estado (SP ou RJ) e idade. E então uma função para retorno de quantas pessoas são do mesmo estado. Como poderia ser feito? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este exemplo receberá uma lista (de listas) de qualquer tamanho, associará às variáveis `nome`, `uf` e `idade` e somará os valores de `uf`:

```
def conta_ufs(pessoas):
    ufs = {}
    for pessoa in pessoas:
        nome, uf, idade = pessoa
        ufs[uf] = ufs.get(uf, 0) + 1
    return ufs

lista_de_pessoas = [
    ['Alexandre', 'AL', 35], ['Larissa', 'BA', 43], ['Carla', 'CE', 25],
    ['Joaquim', 'CE', 19], ['Nelson', 'RJ', 22], ['Sandra', 'RJ', 39],
    ['Reinaldo', 'MG', 49], ['Mariana', 'RN', 33], ['Luciano', 'SE', 15],
    ['Heitor', 'MG', 39]
]

print conta_ufs(lista_de_pessoas)
```

O total de cada estado fica armazenado no dicionário `ufs`, atualizado na linha `ufs[uf] = ufs.get(uf, 0) + 1` que recupera o valor corrente para o estado (ou zero caso ele não exista) e incrementa em um.

O resultado final é um dicionário contendo a sigla do estado e o total de ocorrências nele:

```
{'MG': 2, 'BA': 1, 'AL': 1, 'CE': 2, 'SE': 1, 'RN': 1, 'RJ': 2}
```

Como separo `nome` e `idade` é possível aproveitar o laço para efetuar outras operações (média de idade, maior nome etc).